# Why razor views in WebView App (Android) Project won't recognize the Model?

Tags: android, razor, xamarin, hybrid-mobile-app

The project is created with Xamarin for Visual Studio 2013. At first, .cshtml file won't recognize @model directive. It seems that razor engine was not configured correctly. Then I configure web.config in views folder of my project, so that the version of assemblies match the exact version of assemblies I've installed.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Ototim.Mobile.Droid" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

And it did work, @model directive can be recognized. But then, when I call Model Property in .cshtml file, errors show up

> The name 'Model' does not exist in the current context

on every .cshtml file that contain model even I have declared the type of model using @model directive and the generated code behind does contain Model property.

```
@using Ototim.Mobile.Droid.Models
@model BoyKms
```

And generated code behind.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("RazorTemplatePreprocessor", "3.11.0.0")]
    public partial class RazorView : RazorViewBase
    {

    #line hidden

    #line 2 "RazorView.cshtml"
    public BoyKms Model { get; set; }

    #line default
    #line hidden
    //and so on...
```

Deploying project still work and it shows no error at runtime, but when the project become more complex, I think it will be much easier to code if Intellisense can recognize the model.